# Child element wider than parent element

Tags: html, css

I started learning HTML and CSS and encountered the following problem.
It is said, that a child element is always (as of now) smaller than the parent container.
Here is the thing I don't understand.

```css
.img-container {
   border: 10px solid crimson;
   width: 100px;
}

.img {
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container>
   <img
     scr="apple.jpg"
     class="img"
   />
</div>
```

**And this is what I get in the browser**:
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwgbQ.png)

I've researched a lot but still didn't get it.
Why is the child element (the image) wider than the parent container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do understand that you gave the image a width of 300px when your container has a width of 100px right? i mean you literally made the image wider than container yourself

you can use `overflow` to handle this. give `overflow:hidden` to your container to hide anything that does not fit inside it. or `overflow:auto` to scroll.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that it still couldn't be wider, even if I set it manually. Am I wrong?

Comment: its not like that. if you want the child element to fit inside the container, you should set the child width less or equal to the parent. on the other hand, you can give your parent  overflow: hidden; to hide everything that does not fit inside it. or overflow:auto to scroll.

Comment: @ChiefHan There is a CSS property called 'overflow', which you can set to something like **hidden**, **scroll**, or **auto** to get different results when the child element is larger than the parent element. But CSS will never prevent you from making the child element larger than the parent. This is also why its a good idea to use percent based values or width/height.